# How to use inputview through UITableViewRowAction swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inputview, uitableviewrowaction

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780599/add-datepicker-in-uiactionsheet-using-swift) guide and impelemented it inside:

```
let doneItem = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "  Done  ") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in }
```

but assigning the 'inputView' is where I'm stuck at.

I tried assigning it to the tableView's input view where in the documentation, it says:

*"The value of this read-only property is nil. A responder object that requires a custom view to gather input from the user should redeclare this property as read-write and use it to manage its custom input view."*

So I tried to redeclare the inputView for the tableView by following [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/input-accessorizing-uiviewcontroller) guide but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. If there is a better way of implementing this, I'd like to know. But if there is anyone who is also looking for this solution, here is how I did it.

I added a UITextView through the interface builder and checked the Hidden attribute in the view category under attribute inspector so that  user doesn't activate the textfield by accident. Then:

```
func datePickerSetupTest() {
    let dateView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 160))
    datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
    dateView.addSubview(datePicker)
    inputTextField.inputView = dateView
    let doneButton = UIButton (frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 44))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerSelected", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor .blueColor()
    inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneButton
}
func datePickerSelected() {
    print("selectedRow: \(selectedRow!)")
    inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

and inside the UITableViewRowAction:

```
 tableView.editing = false
 self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
 self.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

I'm using the variable selectedView: Int? to pass the selected row to manipulate the data in that row.