# Why is the DatePicker not displaying in the confirmationDialog?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-datepicker

I'm trying to put a `DatePicker()` in a `.confirmationDialog`, but it's not displaying. My overall goal is to try and replicate the Journal app (in iOS 17.2 beta), so I need this look at least. I'm completely stuck, so even a vague pointer or idea might help me get to the solution.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DatePickerInConfirmationDialog: View {
    @State var showDialog = false
    @State var date = Date.now
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open dialog") {showDialog = true}
            .confirmationDialog("Set Custom Date", isPresented: $showDialog) {
                DatePicker("Enter date", selection: $date)
                    .datePickerStyle(.compact)
                    .frame(height: 400)
            } message: {
                Text("Set Date")
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DatePickerInConfirmationDialog()
}
```

`DatePicker()` in the 'Journal' App (iOS 17.2 beta):
[image: .comfirmationDialog with DatePicker()]

`DatePicker()` in my app:
[image: .comfirmationDialog missing DatePicker()]

Comment: seems a `.sheet(...)` would be better suited for this.

Comment: but its been done in the Journal app, and i like the look and want to try and replicate it

Comment: is the `Journal app` code exactly like yours?

Comment: idk because it isnt my app and cant see the code

Comment: You don't have access to all the APIs that Apple has access to, so don't expect to replicate everything in the Journal app.

Comment: I should've put this in the question (I've updated it now), but I _am_ trying to replicate teh Journal app, because I thought i could, so i need that look at least

Comment: @WorkingDogsupportukraine yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554480/5133585) is an existing answer for how to show a `UIDatePicker` in an action sheet, in UIKit.

Note that a `confirmationDialog` in SwiftUI doesn't necessarily show an action sheet. I think it could be presented as just an alert depending on size classes, so you might have to check the size classes if you want to 100% replicate the same behaviour.

The solution adds a view to `UIAlertController.view`, which the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) tells you explicitly not to do. There likely isn't a "proper" way to do this because of that, unless Apple adds dedicated APIs to do this in future iOS versions.

We can port it to SwiftUI by using a hidden (zero-sized) `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to present the `UIAlertController`.

```
struct DatePickerActionSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    
    let doneClicked: ((Date) -> Void)?
    let cancelClicked: (() -> Void)?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        context.coordinator.vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.doneClicked = {
            isPresented = false
            doneClicked?($0)
        }
        context.coordinator.cancelClicked = {
            isPresented = false
            cancelClicked?()
        }
        if isPresented {
            context.coordinator.present()
        }
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        .zero
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        
        var doneClicked: ((Date) -> Void)?
        var cancelClicked: (() -> Void)?
        
        func present() {
            let dateChooserAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            dateChooserAlert.view.addSubview(datePicker)
            dateChooserAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    self.doneClicked?(datePicker.date)
                }))
            
            dateChooserAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
                    self.cancelClicked?()
                }))
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                datePicker.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateChooserAlert.view.leftAnchor),
                datePicker.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateChooserAlert.view.rightAnchor),
                datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateChooserAlert.view.topAnchor),
                // You'd need to adjust this 500 constant according to how many buttons you have
                dateChooserAlert.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
            ])
            
            vc.present(dateChooserAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@State var isPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Select Date") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        DatePickerActionSheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            print($0)
        } cancelClicked: {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider adding a `@Binding` for the selected date, instead of getting it from the `doneClicked` closure.