# How do I make an toggle button inside an alert in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-alert

I want to show a toggle button inside alert

```
.alert(
    Text("Create"),
    isPresented: $showCreate
) {
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {

    }
    Button("Enter") {
       //some function
    }
    TextField("Name", text: $Name)
    TextField("Key (Optional)", text: $Key)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    Toggle("permanent", isOn: $isPermanent)
} message: {
    Text("Please enter details.")
}
```

it shows toggle as button named "permanent" in between cancel and enter button

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77377805/5133585), where I added a `UIDatePIcker` to an action sheet. An alert is basically an action sheet  with a different `UIAlertController.Style`, so you can apply the same technique with a `UISwitch` too. Do note that Apple does not endorse adding random things into an alert.